# visual studio console program crashes after control-c

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm using the latest update of Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.5.0 Preview 2.0) and trying to intercept the control-c event. But for some reason the console program always crashes before calling my handler. By the way, the program crashes if even I don't install any handler.

Could this be a bug in the compiler? In general, how do you debug something like this?

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

uint64_t iterations;
bool running;

BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType)
{
    switch (fdwCtrlType) {
        case CTRL_C_EVENT: {
            running = false;
            return TRUE;
        } break;
        default: {
            return FALSE;
        } break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(CtrlHandler, TRUE)) {
        std::cout << "Could not install control handler" << std::endl;
    }
    running = true;
    while (running) {
        iterations++;
    }
    std::cout << "Terminated after " << iterations << " iterations." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It isn't crashing.  The debugger is stopping execution when the exception is thrown, before your handler is invoked.  If you tell the debugger to continue execution you should see the program handle it.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Ah, I actually read the doc regarding the debugger, but didn't realize this was how debugger would "handle" the exception. Thanks! 

Interestingly, in release build, `running` is still not set to false after I continue the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler

Here it says that if an application is being debugged, "the system generates a DBG_CONTROL_C exception. This exception is raised only for the benefit of the debugger". Hence it isn't chrashing; you can continue excectution and it should work fine. The documentation says:

> If the debugger passes the exception on unhandled, CTRL+C is passed to the console process and treated as a signal, as previously discussed.